# Problemas con Matrices dinámicas en java

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo Java y tengo un problema con las matrices dinámicas, en este caso guardo nombres en la matriz, las filas y las columnas debe ingresarlas el usuario, así como el nombre que va en cada espacio de la matriz. Al momento de empezar a ingresar los nombres el ciclo for se salta la posición [0][0] y salta a la posición [0][1 , dejando la posición [0][0] vacía.

Código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MatrizD{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc =  new Scanner(System.in);
    int filas , columnas;
    System.out.println("Cuantas filas deseas?: ");
    filas = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Cuantas columnas deseas?: ");
    columnas = sc.nextInt();
    String nombres[][] = new String [filas][columnas];  
    for(int i = 0; i < nombres.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < nombres[i].length; j++){
            System.out.println("Ingresa el nombre de la fila " + i + " y la columna " + j);
            nombres[i][j] = sc.nextLine();
        }
    }

    for(int f = 0; f < nombres.length; f++){
        for(int c = 0; c < nombres[f].length; c++){
            System.out.print("["+nombres[f][c]+"]");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

}

Tomando como ejemplo una matriz de 2x2 la salida del programa es la siguiente:

[image: Salida del programa.]

¿Saben por que sucede esto?

De antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia el `nextLine` dentro del ciclo por un simple `next`:

```
nombres[i][j] = sc.next();
```

Lo que pasa es que cuando llamas a la función `nextInt` te devuelve el número que ingresas y el cursor queda posicionado justo después del número digitado pero queda un remanente después del cursor equivalente al cambio de línea `\n` y cuando llamas a `nextLine` lo toma como si lo hubieras ingresado y continúa la ejecución.

Comment: Me funciono perfecto, no tenia conocimiento sobre eso.